# jQuery click on element included via script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that pulls in a form and I want to perform a click action once that button has been clicked, however because I'm including the form via a script, I can't seem to get the jQuery on my server to interact with it - perhaps because that's the way jQuery works, but is there any way, or a work around, where I can get a click event to work on a form element that has been included via a script?

The JS

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/current.js"></script>
```

My JS

```
    $(".actions input").click(function() {
        $(".pop-up").hide();
        $(".pop-up-thanks").show();
    });
```

Comment: Event delegation might help you out: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delegate event handlers for dynamic objects

You are targeting an element which is being dynamically inserted, therefore the event must be delegated. We can delegate it by using the `on()` method, which must be bound to a static object to achieve delegation. We could bind `on()` to `(document)`, but it's advisable to use a closer scoped object such as  `$("#parent")` to be performant.

```
$("#parent").on( "click", ".actions input", function() {
    $(".pop-up").hide();
    $(".pop-up-thanks").show();
});
```

---

`bind()`, `live()` and `delegate()` are predecessors of `on()`. At the moment, only `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `on()`, while `bind()` and `delegate()` continue to coexist with `on` -- though `on()` is preferred.

### [`.bind()` method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document.

### [`.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation.

### [`.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: That would be ***exactly*** the same as the OP's ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: I'll just edit it for you to the correct syntax

Comment: Did you even read his link?

Comment: This code actually works - can you tell me why it works?

Comment: I thought you were saying .on() and .click() were indistinct, I was going to prepend the target's container, thanks for edit anyway.

Comment: @JackWilliam - `on` and `click` the way you wrote are exactly the same, `click` calls `on` internally. To make a difference it has to be delegated.